# How to read a csv file from an FTP using PySpark in Databricks Community

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I am trying to fetch a file using FTP (kept on Hostinger) using Pyspark in Databricks community.

Everything works fine until I try to read that file using `spark.read.csv('MyFile.csv')`.
Following is the code and an error,

PySpark Code:

```
res=spark.sparkContext.addFile('ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@URL/<folder_name>/MyFile.csv')
myfile=SparkFiles.get("MyFile.csv")
spark.read.csv(path=myfile)                             # Errors out here
print(myfile, sc.getRootDirectory())                    # Outputs almost same path (except dbfs://)
```

Error:

```
AnalysisException: Path does not exist: dbfs:/local_disk0/spark-ce4b313e-00cf-4f52-80d8-dff98fc3eea5/userFiles-90cd99b4-00df-4d59-8cc2-2e18050d395/MyFile.csv
```

Comment: Please make it a two-step process. Use utilities like lftp and download the data and copy it to DBFS.  Step 2: Use the dbfs file for processing.

Answer (score 0):

As the spark.addfile downloads file on driver while databricks uses dbfs as default storage you are getting the error please try below code to see if it fixes your issue

```
res=spark.sparkContext.addFile('ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@URL/<folder_name>/MyFile.csv')
myfile=SparkFiles.get("MyFile.csv")
spark.read.csv(path='file:'+myfile)                            
print(myfile, sc.getRootDirectory())
```